# Export as .txt showing all <p> lines side by side instead of line by line javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to export the content in a div as a .txt file. But all the paragraphs are rendered side by side.

For example, I am having lines as below in a div content:

```
<div id="content>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>How are you</p>
</div>
```

I want to get output in txt file as below

```
 hello
 How are you
```

But am getting the output as

```
 hello How are you
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j046xfoy/

Comment: Your fiddle is pretty useless as it doesn't show the problem, however this is most likely a CSS issue. If you inspect the `p` element in the DOM inspector you probably have set `display: inline`, or `float: left` on them. Check where that rule it set and remove it, or add a new rule that overrides it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have not given any style its my code working properly in my system. There might be problem with fiddle

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Here is th working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zarich/TzVd3/378/

Comment: Did you tried my script ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `.textContent` instead of `.innerText`:

- `.innerText` displays how text looks when in HTML
- `.textContent` displays text as raw `textNodes`

see the difference in the Snippet below:

**SNIPPET**

```css
/* Styles are for demonstration */
#text {
  border:1px solid blue;
  float:right;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height:100%;
  max-width:55%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="text">
    <p>Ying 
      and Yang,</p>
    <p style="visibility:hidden">Black and White</p>
    <p>Evil and Good</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var iText = text.innerText;
    var tContent = text.textContent;
    console.log('innerText: \n' + iText);
    console.log('textContent: \n' + tContent);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery.

Html :

```
 <div id="content">
 <p>hello</p>
 <p>How are you</p>
 </div>
 <a href="#" id="downloadLink">Export as .txt</a><br>
```

Javascript :

```
var root = document.getElementById('content');
var arr =[];
var texts = [].map.call( root.querySelectorAll("p"), function(v){
return v.textContent || v.innerText || "";
});

for (var i in texts) {
arr = arr + texts[i];
arr += "\r\n" //new line
}

$("#downloadLink").click(function() {
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(arr);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
hiddenElement.click('downloadLink');
});
```

Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vLgdmzcy/)